# Prepend fake posts to WordPress search query results

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to insert a few fake posts into my WordPress search results. Using the pre_get_posts hook, I am able to get the function to trigger, but I am not able to prepend the fake posts to the WordPress results.

I followed another post about inserting fake posts. The article mention inserting the fake post into the wp-cache.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function extra_search_items($query) {
  if ($query->is_search && !is_admin()) {

    global $wp, $wp_query;

    $FakePosts = array(
            array(
              'ID'           => -199,
              'post_title'   => 'Fake 1',
              'post_content' => 'This is a fake virtual post.',
              'post_date'    => '2018-06-22 00:00:00',
              'comment_status' => 'closed',
              'post_type'     => 'post'
             ),
            array(
              'ID'           => -200,
              'post_title'   => 'Fake 2',
              'post_content' => 'This is a fake virtual post.',
              'post_date'    => '2018-06-22 00:00:00',
              'comment_status' => 'closed',
              'post_type'     => 'post'
             )

    );

    $i = 0;

    $post = array();

      foreach ($FakePosts as $blog) {

             // create the post and fill up the fields
             $post[$i] = new WP_Post((object)array(
              'ID'           => $blog['ID'],
              'post_title'   => $blog['post_title'],
              'post_content' => $blog['post_content'],
              'post_date'    => $blog['post_date'],
              'comment_status' => $blog['comment_status'],
              'post_type'     => $blog['post_type']
             ));

             if(!wp_cache_get($post[$i]->ID, 'posts')) {
              wp_cache_set($post[$i]->ID, $post[$i], 'posts');
              array_unshift($wp_query->posts, $post[$i]);
              $wp_query->post_count++;

             }
          $i++;
      }
  }

  return $wp_query;

}
add_action('pre_get_posts','extra_search_items');
```

Answer (score 0):

You created fakeposts array, but you are not combining the fakeposts with with the original posts.

Combine the two arrays and loop it then it will display fakeposts also,

like the following

```
function extra_search_items($query) {
  if ($query->is_search && !is_admin()) {

    global $wp, $wp_query;

    $FakePosts1 = array(
            array(
              'ID'           => -199,
              'post_title'   => 'Fake 1',
              'post_content' => 'This is a fake virtual post.',
              'post_date'    => '2018-06-22 00:00:00',
              'comment_status' => 'closed',
              'post_type'     => 'post'
             ),
            array(
              'ID'           => -200,
              'post_title'   => 'Fake 2',
              'post_content' => 'This is a fake virtual post.',
              'post_date'    => '2018-06-22 00:00:00',
              'comment_status' => 'closed',
              'post_type'     => 'post'
             )

    );

    $i = 0;

    $post = array();
    $FakePosts_array = array_merge($FakePosts1,$FakePosts)
      foreach ($FakePosts_array as $blog) {

             // create the post and fill up the fields
             $post[$i] = new WP_Post((object)array(
              'ID'           => $blog['ID'],
              'post_title'   => $blog['post_title'],
              'post_content' => $blog['post_content'],
              'post_date'    => $blog['post_date'],
              'comment_status' => $blog['comment_status'],
              'post_type'     => $blog['post_type']
             ));

             if(!wp_cache_get($post[$i]->ID, 'posts')) {
              wp_cache_set($post[$i]->ID, $post[$i], 'posts');
              array_unshift($wp_query->posts, $post[$i]);
              $wp_query->post_count++;

             }
          $i++;
      }
  }

  return $wp_query;

}
add_action('pre_get_posts','extra_search_items');
```